# How do I use ctypes to set a library's extern function pointer to a Python callback function?

Tags: python, ctypes

Some C libraries export function pointers such that the user of the library sets that function pointer to the address of their own function to implement a hook or callback.

In this example library `liblibrary.so`, how do I set library_hook to a Python function using ctypes?

library.h:

```
typedef int exported_function_t(char**, int);
extern exported_function_t *library_hook;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is tricky in ctypes because ctypes function pointers do not implement the `.value` property used to set other pointers. Instead, cast your callback function and the extern function pointer to `void *` with the `c_void_p` function. After setting the function pointer as `void *` as shown, C can call your Python function, and you can retrieve the function as a function pointer and call it with normal ctypes calls.

```
from ctypes import *

liblibrary = cdll.LoadLibrary('liblibrary.so')

def py_library_hook(strings, n):
    return 0

# First argument to CFUNCTYPE is the return type:
LIBRARY_HOOK_FUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_char_p), c_int)
hook = LIBRARY_HOOK_FUNC(py_library_Hook)
ptr = c_void_p.in_dll(liblibrary, 'library_hook')
ptr.value = cast(hook, c_void_p).value
```